# Probability to find random digit number in another random digit number

Tags: probability

I'm wandering how to find the probability let's say to find 10-random-digit number in 1.000.000-random-digit-number?

So how to find $P$ of question stated above?

Answer (score 0):

Your example is wrong already.

There are $9^6$ numbers of length 6 that do not contain a $1$.

Probability is something like $1-(0.9)^6$.

Calculating the exact numbers/formula of the 10 random digit example is much harder, and requires inclusion/exclusion method.

Also finding $11$ and finding $12$ is calculated differently I think.

But my first order estimate would be something like $1-0.9999999999^{100000}$

Comment: Sorry about the example, I'm still student in a highschool. But isn't it supposed to be like $1-0.0000000009^{100000}$?

Comment: Nope. You calculate the chance that it can't be found. And the chance that 10 digits don't match 10 other digits is 0.9999999999. However, if you repeat this 1.000.000 times, the chances must be multiplied 1.000.000 times.

Comment: so it's a pretty big chance then?

Comment: Pretty big chance of NOT finding the pattern.